# Update existing find and replace macro (folder level) to also work on subfolders and would like popup to allow direct folder address entry if possible

Tags: vba, ms-word, subdirectory

I have a find and replace macro that updates rtf files at the folder level. I'd like this macro to also be able to update rtf files in subfolders as well. Additionally, the current macro dialog box requires user to select the folder that contains the rtf files each time the macro is run. I'd prefer to have the option to enter the location of the parent folder either directly in the dialog box (my preference) or hard code the parent folder directory into the macro. Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated as I am not very good with VBA.

Here is the full macro:

```
Sub UpdateBODY()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, wdDoc As Document, Rng As Range
    Dim Sctn As Section, HdFt As HeaderFooter, Fnd As String, Rep As String
    Dim protection As Long
    Fnd = "ACCOUNTING": Rep = "FINANCE"
    strFolder = GetFolder
    If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.rtf", vbNormal)
    While strFile <> ""
        Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=True)
        With wdDoc
            'record current protection type and unprotect if necessary
            protection = .ProtectionType
            If protection <> wdNoProtection Then .Protect wdNoProtection
            'Process everything except headers & footers
            For Each Rng In .StoryRanges
                Select Case Rng.StoryType
                    Case wdPrimaryFooterStory, wdFirstPageFooterStory, wdEvenPagesFooterStory, _
                        wdPrimaryHeaderStory, wdFirstPageHeaderStory, wdEvenPagesHeaderStory
                    Case Else
                        Call RngFndRep(Rng, Fnd, Rep)
                End Select
            Next
            'reapply protection if necessary
            If protection <> wdNoProtection Then .Protect protection
            .Close SaveChanges:=True
        End With
        strFile = Dir()
    Wend
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
Dim oFolder As Object
GetFolder = ""
Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function

Sub RngFndRep(Rng As Range, Fnd As String, Rep As String)
With Rng.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Format = False
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .Text = Fnd
  .Replacement.Text = Rep
  .MatchCase = True
  .MatchAllWordForms = False
  .MatchWholeWord = False
  .MatchWildcards = False
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub
```

Attempted to run this macro on a parent folder that has appx 50 child folders and each child folder has approximately 100 rtf files. I want to be able to select the single parent folder, run the macro, and macro runs on all rtf files within the child folder.

Comment: See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/117894-post8.html

Comment: Thanks macropod, unfortunately this doesn't answer my question but i appreciate your response.

Comment: The code in that thread is written explicitly to process a folder and its sub-folders. The only things you'd need to do is replace it's 'With wdDoc ... End With' code with yours and its FndRepRng sub with your RngFndRep sub. What more do you want?

Comment: I've tried splicing what you have indicated to my code but keep getting undefined errors, I'm probably not integrating the two codes together properly, but I'll keep trying -- I'm very new to vba so what may seem very simple to a seasoned vba users is a little more difficult for me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unless you tell us what those errors relate to - and VBA does say that - we can only guess.

Comment: I get a compile error that says 'Variable not defined' and the following item is highlighted in debug mode 'Sub UpdateDocuments (oFolder As String)'...

Comment: I appreciate your directions but they are not clear for me and that is my fault because I think you expect that I can interpret or fill in the blanks of anything you left out but that  is just not the case. If I followed your directions word for word, I actually end up with code that doesnt even have a place to define the text to find and replace. Thanks again for your response but I think you are more used to working with more seasoned vba users which I am not. I do appreciate your attempt to help though and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim FSO As Object, oFolder As Object, StrFolds As String
 
Sub Main()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim TopLevelFolder As String, TheFolders As Variant, aFolder As Variant, i As Long
TopLevelFolder = GetFolder
If TopLevelFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
StrFolds = vbCr & TopLevelFolder
If FSO Is Nothing Then
  Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
End If
'Get the sub-folder structure
Set TheFolders = FSO.GetFolder(TopLevelFolder).SubFolders
For Each aFolder In TheFolders
  RecurseWriteFolderName (aFolder)
Next
'Process the documents in each folder
For i = 1 To UBound(Split(StrFolds, vbCr))
  Call UpdateDocuments(CStr(Split(StrFolds, vbCr)(i)))
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub RecurseWriteFolderName(aFolder)
Dim SubFolders As Variant, SubFolder As Variant
Set SubFolders = FSO.GetFolder(aFolder).SubFolders
StrFolds = StrFolds & vbCr & CStr(aFolder)
On Error Resume Next
For Each SubFolder In SubFolders
  RecurseWriteFolderName (SubFolder)
Next
End Sub
 
Function GetFolder() As String
Dim oFolder As Object
GetFolder = ""
Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function

Sub UpdateDocuments(oFolder As String)
Dim strFile As String, wdDoc As Document, Rng As Range
Dim Sctn As Section, HdFt As HeaderFooter, Prot As Long
Const Fnd As String = "ACCOUNTING": Const Rep As String = "FINANCE"
strFile = Dir(oFolder & "\*.rtf", vbNormal)
While strFile <> ""
  Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=oFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  With wdDoc
    'record current protection type and unprotect if necessary
    Prot = .ProtectionType
    If Prot <> wdNoProtection Then .Unprotect
    'Process everything except headers & footers
    For Each Rng In .StoryRanges
      Select Case Rng.StoryType
        Case wdPrimaryFooterStory, wdFirstPageFooterStory, wdEvenPagesFooterStory, _
          wdPrimaryHeaderStory, wdFirstPageHeaderStory, wdEvenPagesHeaderStory
        Case Else
          Call RngFndRep(Rng, Fnd, Rep)
      End Select
    Next
    'reapply protection if necessary
    If Prot <> wdNoProtection Then .Protect Prot
    .Close SaveChanges:=True
  End With
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
Set wdDoc = Nothing
End Sub

Sub RngFndRep(Rng As Range, Fnd As String, Rep As String)
With Rng.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Format = False
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .Text = Fnd
  .Replacement.Text = Rep
  .MatchCase = True
  .MatchAllWordForms = False
  .MatchWholeWord = False
  .MatchWildcards = False
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub
```

**Note:** if the protection includes a password, you'll need to supply that - and re-apply it later. For a demonstration, see:

https://www.msofficeforums.com/32288-post4.html

and, if all documents use the same password:

https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/27809-code-add-new-row-table.html

Comment: That works perfectly @macropod, you have no idea how thankful I am for your help. Thank you again and sorry that I such a novice. Ive marked your answer as best answer. Not to push my luck and no worries if you think I should post this as a seperate question (maybe it should be its own question) but is there a way to define the folder that I want the code to run on directly in the code so that I don't have to select the folder each time I run the script. Again, you've helped me enough so no worries at all if you don't have time for that or if you think it should be another post.

Comment: «is there a way to define the folder that I want the code to run on directly in the code so that I don't have to select the folder each time I run the script» To do that, simply replace 'GetFolder' in TopLevelFolder = GetFolder with the required path in double-quotes (e.g. TopLevelFolder = "C:\Users\Michael\Downloads\Test").

Comment: Works perfectly @macropod, thanks again for your time, expertise, and patience. I wish you all the best!